# Two ways of viewing a char ** pointer chain and can pointer types be mixed?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have the variable declaration `char **p`. Does that mean that `p` is a pointer to a `char` pointer or that `p` is a pointer to a pointer of some type that points to a `char`?

There is a subtle difference between these two chains of pointers.

In other words, what I am trying to ask is given a `char` pointer to a pointer `char **p`, `*p` can obviously be a pointer to a `char *`, but could it also point to some other pointer type like `void *` which in turn points to a `char`?

Comment: `*p` *must* be `char *`… "pointer to char pointer" means a "pointer to `char *`" means `char **`.  "pointer to pointer to char" means a "pointer to `char *`" means `char **`. The terms "char pointer" and "pointer to char" are just different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you're distinguishing "char pointer" and "pointer to a char".

Comment: It’s easy to figure that out by yourself. Try compiling both and compare the results.

Comment: When reading some 'pointy' statement in C, read it from right to left.  I.E. "p is a pointer to a pointer to char"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C programming language `char **p` will be described as, p is a pointer of pointer to a char. That means p can hold a address of another char pointer.

For example:-

```
char c = 'A';
char *b = &c;// here b is a char pointer so it can hold the address of a char variable which is c
char **p = &b;// p is a pointer of pointer to a char so here it can hold the address of a pointer of char i.e. b.

printf("%c", **p);// correct and will print A
```

Now here p is not a void pointer but you can make p also a void * pointer. So following is also correct

```
void **p = &b;
```

But to get the value of `char c` we have to type cast it like below

```
printf("%c", **p);// Not correct and will not print A

printf("%c", **((char **)p));//correct, first we type cast it to a pointer of pointer to char and dereference it to get the value stored in c
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of `*p` is always `char *`. It cannot be a `void*` that happens to be pointing to a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer types are derived from some other type - an object type, a function type, or an incomplete type. The type from which the pointer is derived is called its *reference type* (C99, 6.2.5.20).

The reference type of `char**` is `char*`, meaning that dereferencing `char**` expression yields a `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer contains an address. The C compiler uses the variable type such as `char` of a definition such as `char *pC;` to know how to access the data at the address contained in the pointer variable `pC`. So to C all addresses are pretty much the same, at least for all the main stream computer architectures, and the type just tells the C compiler how many bytes of memory to access when dereferencing the pointer or dereferencing the pointer pointed to by a variable.

So a definition such as `char **p;` tells the compiler that the variable `p` contains the address of a memory location, which is accessed by reading the number of bytes of a pointer, that points to another address, which is accessed by reading the number of bytes of a pointer, and that the address pointed to contains the address of a `char`.

And remember that with the C programming language you can use a cast to persuade the compiler to accept almost anything.

And a `void *` pointer variable is by definition capable of holding a pointer to any data type.

However it is your responsibility that what you are doing actually makes sense. So it is assumed the `void *` pointer contains the address of a character; that when the variable `char **p;` is dereferenced as in `char aChar = **p;` it is up to the programmer that the variable `p` contains a valid address and that the memory location whose address is pointed to, `*p`, contains a valid address. Or if you are doing something like `char aStr[128]; strcpy (aStr, *p);` then the pointer address pointed to by `*p` contains the address of a zero terminated string of characters.

And to some extent it depends on the C compiler. Some are more accepting than others. Some will issue warnings and some may issue errors and it probably also depends heavily on the compiler options selected for the compile.

Doing a test compile with Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition I can do the following:

```
char  aStr[] = "this is a string";
void *p = aStr;   // perfectly fine
char *pc = aStr;  // perfectly fine
char **pp = &p;   // warning C4133: 'initializing': incompatible types - from 'void **' to 'char **'
char **pp2 = (char **)&p;  // perfectly fine since we are casting the pointer
char **pp3 = &aStr; // warning C4047: 'initializing': 'char **' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[17]'
```

By the way, the last definition, `char **pp3 = &aStr;` really should be an error since if you dereference `pp3` you do not get a valid pointer to a string.

However using the debugger to look at `pp`, it points to a valid pointer to a string and I can see the text of `aStr`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the right-left rule on the declaration you’d see that:

1. you start with identifier p (P)
2. p has nothing on the right
3. you go left to the first * pointer (*P)
4. you go left again and you see * pointer (**P)
5. then you go left again and see char (char **P)

all together you can make the conclusion:

P is a pointer to a pointer to char.

Which is a fancy way of saying P is a double pointer to char.